# Сортировка русских дат

Tags: php, sqlite

Добрый день, возникла проблема такого характера. Используется SQLite, мне нужно сортировать дату на русской локализации(с английской все ок отрабатывает) Фишка в том, что дата хранится в базе, типом поля "TEXT"(насколько я знаю тип "Date"-нету в SQLite). Сайт изначально писал не я, мне нужно сделать доработки. Принцип такой, человек через админку вручную может добавить какую-то новость. В поле "Дата добавления:", они ручками пишут дату какую хотят. Они могут написать 13 сентября 2018, или 13 сИнтября 2018, не важно. 
Как работает код:
$media = $db->exec('SELECT * from media WHERE lang=1');
lang 1 = русская локализация.
В общем, в переменной $media лежит такой вот массив:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 28
        [lang] => 1
        [img] => ../uploads/media/posts/prrrrrrr.png
        [title] => Кasdasd
        [description] =>                                                                    Гasdasdasd                                                            
        [source] => МинФин
        [s_img] => ../uploads/media/posts/2018-02-20-11-39-48.png
        [s_link] => google.ru
        [date] => 29 Декабря, 2017
    )
```

И так далее.
Таких новостей там штук 6-7. Как отсортировать поле date? Надеюсь все понятно объяснил.
Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Кхм. Никак, наверное... Вручную привести все имеющиеся записи к единому формату, а потом добавлять даты только в этом формате...

Comment: @АндрейNOP окей, я поисправлял все даты в формат 29 Декабря, 2017, т.е. день, месяц(буквами), год. Возможно ли отсортировать это?

Comment: А зачем месяц буквами-то? Почему не в формате `yyyy-MM-dd`? Это же не для человеков, а для компьютера. Из этого формата уже формировать строку в человеческом виде средствами php (я не специалист в php, поэтому не напишу как). Когда у вас дата будет в этом формате, сортировать вы можете ее просто как строку

Comment: Главное, сделайте, чтобы при дальнейшем добавлении новостей поле ввода было не текстовым, а именно предназначалось для даты, ну или автоматически заполняйте дату по текущей дате.

Comment: @Speakkk а проверку на правильность дат можно проводить по Левенштейну. https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.levenshtein.php

Answer (score 1):

> *могут написать 13 сентября 2018, или 13 сИнтября 2018*
>
> > *Как отсортировать поле date?*

Можно сначала производить преобразование дат в один формат, *(в том числе и не корректных, вида сИнтября)*, и потом сортировать полученный массив. Публикую решение для PHP>=7.

**Массив с разными датами**:

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'id' => 28,
        'lang' => 1,
        'img' => '../uploads/media/posts/prrrrrrr.png',
        'title' => 'Кasdasd',
        'description' => 'Гasdasdasd',
        'source' => 'МинФин',
        's_img' => '../uploads/media/posts/2018-02-20-11-39-48.png',
        's_link' => 'google.ru',
        'date' => '29 Декабря, 2017'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 28,
        'lang' => 1,
        'img' => '../uploads/media/posts/prrrrrrr.png',
        'title' => 'Кasdasd',
        'description' => 'Гasdasdasd',
        'source' => 'МинФин',
        's_img' => '../uploads/media/posts/2018-02-20-11-39-48.png',
        's_link' => 'google.ru',
        'date' => '30 Октября, 2017'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 28,
        'lang' => 1,
        'img' => '../uploads/media/posts/prrrrrrr.png',
        'title' => 'Кasdasd',
        'description' => 'Гasdasdasd',
        'source' => 'МинФин',
        's_img' => '../uploads/media/posts/2018-02-20-11-39-48.png',
        's_link' => 'google.ru',
        'date' => '01 Января, 2018'
    )
);
```

**Корректировка дат**:

```
$arr = array_map(function($item){
    $date = &$item['date'];
    $patt = [
        '~январ[ья]~iu',
        '~ф[ие]врал[ья]~iu',
        '~марта?~iu',
        '~апрел[ья]~iu',
        '~ма[йя]~iu',
        '~июн[ья]~iu',
        '~июл[ья]~iu',
        '~августа?~iu',
        '~с[еи]нтябр[ья]~iu',
        '~октябр[ья]~iu',
        '~ноябр[ья]~iu',
        '~д[еи]кабр[ья]~iu',
        '~[\s,]+~'
    ];
    $repl = [
        '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06',
        '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '.'
    ];
    $date = preg_replace($patt, $repl, $date);
    $date = (new DateTime($date))->format('Y.m.d');
    return $item;
}, $arr);
```

**Сортировка по ключу 'date'**:

```
array_multisort(array_column($arr, 'date'), SORT_NUMERIC, $arr);
```

**Вывод по возростанию**:

```
var_dump($arr);
```

**Или по убыванию**:

```
var_dump( array_reverse($arr) );
```